# Materialize css carousal

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm working with basic carousel provided by Materialize css framework.The default image size is 200*200,
How can I change it without affecting the alignment?

http://materializecss.com/media.html

Comment: It's seems that if you change the width in the css, the plugin calculate the right values and display the images OK. http://jsbin.com/cesehif/edit?html,css,js

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default image size with:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    full_width: true
});
```

And overwrite the CSS and use `"overflow: hidden"`

Answer (score 0):

to change the image size, you can put height and width in img tag

```
<! –– here is the template from materialize css->
<! –– just add width and height as shown here!->
<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img width="your custom width" height='your custom height'src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
</div>
<script> M.AutoInit();</script>
```